# Can a more powerful computing machine (Turing Machine) not decide a problem which can be well decide by less powerful machine in Chomsky hierarchy

Tags: automation, finite-automata, computation-theory, turing-machines

For a set of input alphabets (a,b) , say Language L is defined as "Set of all 2016 length strings".

so,

**First Scenario :**
A finite Automata can clearly decide whether any input given over input alphabets (a,b), is in L or not, by accepting or rejecting it OR in other words it can decide that the input string is of length 2016 or not ?

**Second Scenario :** 
Let's say I wanna see how turing machine works, so even after getting the answer from a less powerful machine, we run that arbitary string on Turing Machine.

But unfortunately, Years passed but the turing machine does not halt, that is - "it has fallen into infinte loop for that arbitary input".

I am very much confused by this fact that why even being more powerful than a finite Automata, a turing machine cannot decide what a Finite Automata decided

Edited:

Example : L = ({M} | M is a turing machine that accepts a string of length 2015)

we know that if we see the above example through the prism of regular language then language of length 2015 are finite and hence they are regular.

But the language L for Turing machine M is Undecidable and Recursively enumerable.

that's more or less my confusion

Answer (score 2):

Turing machines can decide membership in any regular language. I think your confusion is that a TM *can* loop forever, and certainly many TMs do that and many others that don't also don't decide any particular regular language. However, there's guaranteed to be a TM that decides any regular language L:

- take a DFA for L;
- write the input on the tape;
- transition through the DFA based on symbols read from the tape left to right;
- halt-accept if ending in an accepting state;
- halt-reject otherwise

Comment: Thanks for answering but my confusion is regarding the case "NO" , when Turing machine does  not halt on input given, Lets sat the scenario below :

1. A turing machine designed to accept (0+1)* (00 + 11) (0+1)* over {0,1} , which can very well accept the input 100111 , but l let's not give it this input , Lets give some other input which does not belong to this language but will take the encoding of the given Turing machine into infinite loop

Comment: or Equivalently I am adding an example in the description

Comment: @GauravJoshi Not all Turing machines can even enter infinite loops on any inputs. Some Turing machines halt on all inputs. I think this is the confusion. A Turing machine that decides a regular language halts on all inputs. A Turing machine for the empty language simply transitions to halt-reject, always halting. A Turing machine for the language of all strings simply transitions to halt-accept, always halting. Every other regular language has a TM that always halts and correctly decides membership.